How to fix HTTP 405 error in Django when submitting a POST request?
The issue arises when I submit the form. Despite using a POST method in the HTML form and ensuring that my view is correctly handling POST requests, I get an HTTP 405 error.
I can't figure out why Django is rejecting my POST request, even though my view is decorated with @require_POST and @login_required.
views.py
@login_required
@require_POST  # Ensures that the view only handles POST requests
def deposit_view(request):
    allowed_methods = ['POST']  # List of allowed HTTP methods

    # Check if the method is allowed
    if request.method not in allowed_methods:
        return JsonResponse({'error': f"Invalid request method. Expected {', '.join(allowed_methods)}."}, status=405)

    # Handle POST requests
    if request.method == 'POST':
        deposit_type = request.POST.get('deposit_type')
        amount = request.POST.get('amount')
        currency = request.POST.get('currency')

     if deposit_type == 'crypto':
            # Generate a random crypto address (as a placeholder example)
            crypto_address = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=42))
            return JsonResponse({'crypto_address': crypto_address, 'amount': amount})
     elif deposit_type == 'fiat':
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Fiat deposit initiated successfully'})
     else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid deposit type'}, status=400)

deposit.html
Django form submission results in HTTP 405, but POST is correctly defined
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h2>Deposit Funds</h2>
  <form action="{% url 'deposit' %}" method="POST">  <!-- action points to 'deposit' URL -->
    {% csrf_token %} <!-- CSRF Token for protection -->

    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="deposit_type" class="form-label">Deposit Type:</label>
      <select name="deposit_type" id="deposit_type" class="form-select" required>
        <option value="crypto">Cryptocurrency</option>
        <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="amount" class="form-label">Amount:</label>
      <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter amount" required>
    </div>

    <!-- Fiat deposit section -->
    <div id="fiat_deposit" style="display: none;">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="currency" class="form-label">Currency:</label>
        <select name="currency" id="currency" class="form-select">
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Crypto deposit section -->
    <div id="crypto-deposit-section" style="display: none;" class="mt-4">
      <button type="button" id="crypto-deposit-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Crypto Address</button>
      <div id="crypto-deposit-result" class="mt-3"></div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4">Submit Deposit</button>
  </form>

  <div id="payment-result" class="mt-4"></div>
</div>

<!-- Link to the compiled TypeScript file (JavaScript) -->
<script src="{% static 'js/deposit.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}


I am really tired. I have tried everything i know to solve the issue of POST method changing to GET but every solution i came up with is not working.


Did you check (e.g. with the browser debugger) if there's really a post request made?

First, you repeat yourself 3 times. @require_POST / if request.method not in allowed_methods... / if request.method="post" Try commenting all, the just use >> if request.method="post": << and start printing your request contents to the console. Further use the dev tools of your internet browser and see what the html response contains.

@Franz I just did but i still got a GET method instead of POST

@KlausD.  I debug it in my brouser Network and the post request was not there. what i still saw there was a GET method
